# react native: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" trouble with useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to programming and I am having a problem with my react native app. 
after pressing twice on the on/off Button the app stops working and this is the error that I get:
"Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function,
    in Provider (at App.js:40)
    in _default (at withExpoRoot.js:22)"

My guess is that I need to do some kind of clean up but I don't know how to implement it in my code.
this is my code:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Context as PContext } from '../context/PContext';

const PDetailScreen = (navigation) => {
  const { state, fetchSensore } = useContext(PContext);
  const { addMotorStateApp } = useContext(PContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSensore(() => {
        return state;
    });
  }, []);

  const onPress = () => {
    if (state.data.waterMotor) {
      addMotorStateApp(state.data._id, !state.data.waterMotor.state);
    }
    fetchSensore();
  };

  return (
    <>
      {state.data && (
        <>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 28 }}>
            Muister sensor data:
            {state.data &&
              state.data.muisterSensor.tests[
                state.data.muisterSensor.tests.length - 1
              ].status}
          </Text>
        </>
      )}
      <Button
        title="Get  Data"
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() =>
          fetchSensore((state) => {
            return state;
          })
        }
      />

      {state.data && (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
          {state.data.waterMotor.state === 'true' ? (
            <Text>ON</Text>
          ) : (
            <Text>OFF</Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

PDetailScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  title: 'Plnati';
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#00CC00',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default PDetailScreen;
```

I will be grateful if someone explain to me how to solve this problem.

edit-
my Context provider code is this:

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';
import ApiConnect from '../api/ApiConnect';
const URL = '/api/v1/p;

const pReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'fetch_Sensore':
      return action.payload;
    case 'Motor_State':
      console.log(action.payload);
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const fetchSensore = (dispatch) => async () => {
  const response = await ApiConnect.get(`${URL}/Data`);
  dispatch({ type: 'fetch_Sensore', payload: response.data });
};

const addMotorStateApp = (dispatch) => async (id, stateMotor) => {
  const response = await ApiConnect.post(`${URL}/motorstateapp`, {
    id,
    stateMotor,
  });
  dispatch({ type: 'Motor_State', payload: response.data });
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  pReducer,
  {
    fetchSensore,
    addMotorStateApp,
  },
  []
);
```

Comment: can you show your context provider

Comment: yes, Thank you for your time! I add it to the question.

Comment: Ahh, you don't seem to render the Provider component anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what do you mean by render the provider component. Can you give me an example?